# Why am I able to access the class variable of type list and change its contents but not of type string?

Tags: python, oop

I have below code:

```
class Employee:
    orgName = 'Credit Cards'  # class variable

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name  # instance variable

Sam = Employee('Sam')
print(Sam.orgName) # 'Credit Cards'
Sam.orgName = 'Loans'
print(Sam.orgName) # 'Loans'
print(Employee.orgName) # 'Credit Cards'
```

So in the above example I understand that when I assign something to Sam.orgName. Python is actually creating an instance variable called 'orgName' and thus the class variable 'orgName' remains unchanged.

But then I tried below code here is where I am confused:

```
class Employee:
   orgName = 'Credit Cards'  # class variable
   hobbies = ['Hiking']

   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name  # instance variable

Sam = Employee('Sam')
print(Sam.hobbies) # 'Hiking'
Sam.hobbies.append('Reading')
print(Sam.hobbies) # 'Hiking', 'Reading'
print(Employee.hobbies) # 'Hiking', 'Reading'
```

How is it that I am able to modify the class variable here when it should follow the behavior of the first code snippet where Sam.hobbies should have created a list instance variable?

Comment: Why would calling the `append` method of a list that already exists instantiate a new list and rebind `hobbies`? You don't see the same behavior because two completely different things are happening. In the first example, you are explicitly binding `orgName` to a string, shadowing the class variable. In the second example you're modifying a list in-place.

Comment: @PaulM. Because according to my first example calling Sam.orgName created a new instance variable called orgName and did not touch the class variable called orgName. So I was assuming here that Sam.hobbies would have the same behavior.

Comment: "How is it that I am able to modify the class variable here when it should follow the behavior of the first code snippet where Sam.hobbies should have created a list instance variable?" Because in the second example **you never created an instance variable to shadow the class variable**. Instead, you *accessed* the class variable through an instance, `Sam.hobbies` resolves to the class variable, which is referring to a `list` object. You then call `.append("Reading")` on that list object, which mutates that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between how you modified the string member vs the list member. Initially the `Employee` static member is shared by the instance `Sam` (when `Sam` is initiated, it references whatever `Employee` references).

In the list case, you modified this list in-place, which altered the list for both because they point to the same object. In the string case, you changed the *assignment* of the variable for the `Sam`, so that this instance's version of `orgName` no longer points to the same thing as the `Employee` class does. Note that strings are immutable in python, so you could not have done an in-place modification in the same way anyway.

Comment: Well thats kind of my question, in the list example why are they both pointing to the same list object? Sam.hobbies should have created a new list right? According to my first example that is what happened. Why did it instead change the list class variable list instead? Also if thats the case, why didn't the last line in the first snippet print "Loans"?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I understand what you are saying. The key part here I guess is in "when Sam is initiated, it references whatever Employee references)." If I had done Sam.hobbies = [] then it would be the same thing as the String example. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Ultima yes, precseily. Just referencing `Sam.hobbies` doesn't create a new list. *You have to do that explicitly*, e.g. `Sam.hobbies = []`